# Query to calculate the sum from 3 different tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables

Table A:

```
Cid acc_id acc balance
1   345     100
1  456    300
2  347    500
```

Table B:

```
Cid acc_id acc balance
1   348     100
1  457    300
2  349    500
```

Table C:

```
Cid acc_id acc balance
1   340     100
1  457    300
2  344    500
```

I need to create a single table which gives the sum of balances for each customer across all 3 tables.

```
Cid. Balance
1.    1200
2.    1500
```

I need SQL for this purpose. Since customer id is repeating within the table I m confused.

Comment: See about UNION.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Why is there no cid = 3 in the result?

Comment: Shouldn't CID #1 balance be $300 and, CID #2 balance be $900?

Comment: 100 + 100 + 100 = 1200???

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please tag the specific database only.

Comment: Your expected results are inconsistent with your example input. Any form of coding requires attention to detail. Just making sure you get the details right in your question can sometimes get you to the answer, or a lot closer. Please edit your question and fix the inconsistencies and errors.

Comment: Each customer can have diff account and summation should be based on customer id and not account id

Comment: I am using oracle and have edited the question to remove inconsistencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `union all` and aggregation

```
select cid, sum(balance)
from ((select Cid, acc_id, balance
       from a
      ) union all
      (select Cid, acc_id, balance
       from b
      ) union all
      (select Cid, acc_id, balance
       from c
      )
     ) abc
group by cid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL`, as in:

```
select
  cid, 
  sum(balance) as balance 
from (
  select * from table_a
  union all
  select * from table_b
  union all
  select * from table_c
) x
group by cid
```

Comment: I need to sum within table also? Will that be achieved with this?

Comment: @akr Did you try it?